# What does Fl_Region R = (Fl_Region)malloc(sizeof(*R)) mean?

Tags: objective-c, macos, malloc, fltk

Could someone help me decipher these line of code in fltk1.3.0?

```
    extern CGRect fl_cgrectmake_cocoa(int x, int y, int w, int h);
inline Fl_Region XRectangleRegion(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
  Fl_Region R = (Fl_Region)malloc(sizeof(*R));
  R->count = 1;
  R->rects = (CGRect *)malloc(sizeof(CGRect));
  *(R->rects) = fl_cgrectmake_cocoa(x, y, w, h);
  return R;
}
```

I have an issue with a program which uses fltk as a dependency where it fails with the error

000/??? sec ~~(,_,"> [oo]ctffind(1976,0x7fff7a904310) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=18446744071761305600) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

The program author has suggested that it may be a Mac OSX specific problem, and when I run Xcode's instruments to look for Memory allocation and leaks, the main things that are listed are libfltk.1.3.dylib and CoreGraphics for memory allocation, and NSAutoReleasepool in memory leaks. I have tried looking up basic Objective C meanings of the terms, but I am still puzzled about some things, like what does () mean in front of malloc, what pointer R is pointing to (I can't find R defined anywhere else in mac.H), and can it point to R somewhere outside of the mac.H file. Does it look like these lines of code could be on the right track to controlling the memory allocation during the program run to something reasonable?

Comment: Bad code is bad.   That sizeof should be `sizeof(Fl_Region)` and not de-referencing the garbage value of a pointer.  I'd wager that such an expression is undefined by the C language spec and, thus, that it barfs on OS X is simply fallout from the OS X compiler choosing a different random behavior than the other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

### From FLTK doc:

Fl_Region is an operating system specific type.

### From what I interpret in your code:

Fl_Region is a pointer to a structure.
R is declared in the line:

```
Fl_Region R = (Fl_Region)malloc(sizeof(*R));
```

That's why you coudn´t find it anywhere else.
So, that line is trying to allocate enough memory for the structure (of Fl_Region type) pointed by pointer R (i.e. *R)
Then the generic pointer returned by malloc is converted to Fl_Region type. This is what `(Fl_Region)` to the left of malloc does.
It would suggest to follow bbum's advice and change `sizeof(*R)` to `sizeof(Fl_Region)`.